# Schedule a script with arguments using 'at'

Tags: bash, shell-script, at

I have a bash script and I want to run it at a given time.
Usually I would write something like this to run it immediately:

```
./my_script.sh 1 1 n 8 3 keywords here
```

I am trying to execute the same command using the "[at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at)" command but it doesn't work.
If I run this, for example:

```
at 2230 -f my_script.sh 1 1 n 8 3 keywords here
```

I get this error:

```
syntax error. Last token seen: 1
Garbled time
```

How can I run the script with arguments at a given time?

Comment: Does `echo my_script.sh 1 1 n 8 3 keywords here | at 2230` work for you?

Comment: @doneal24 without quotation marks it wasn't working. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The -f option is not needed. Try either:

```
at 2230 my_script.sh 1 1 n 8 3 keywords here
```

or

```
echo 'my_script.sh 1 1 n 8 3 keywords here' | at 2230
```

`at -f myFile` copies that whole file directly into the at-job file immediately. It does not have a mechanism to pass the args to the script.

The two alternatives I show copy just the command itself into the at-job file. The script-plus-args is then invoked at 2230.

The at-job file contains a script to recreate your environment first, so PATH, cwd and most other stuff is available.

It is advised that scripts have a shebang because at may initially invoke a different shell to your online one.

Changing or removing the script before 1030 may be unwise (although I considered it a useful facility to bug-fix job scripts before they ran).

Comment: Thanks! I used the second approach and it worked perfectly :)